# Regular compound verbs with irregular root verbs

Tags: verb

The verb **gleiten** has past and perfect forms

> glitt, hat geglitten

**Entgleiten** is also irregular, with the same forms

> entglitt, ist entglitten

But **begleiten** is regular:

> begleitete, hat begleitet

The [Duden entry](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/begleiten) of **begleiten** says

> **Herkunft**
>
> Vermischung von gleichbedeutend veraltetem beleiten (mittelhochdeutsch beleiten, althochdeutsch bileiten) mit ↑geleiten

It seems that the reason why **begleiten** has a different past and perfect forms than **gleiten** is that it is not derived from **gleiten**, but rather a mix of **beleiten** and **geleiten**.

What are some other examples of verbs that have different past/perfect forms than their (apparent) roots? How common is this phenomenon?

Comment: Gleiten, ausgleiten, entgleiten, Gleis, glatt, glitschig ist eine Wortfamilie, die etwas mit der Beschaffenheit einer Oberfläche zu tun hat, sodass bei Bewegung auf dieser Oberfläche sehr geringe Reibung vorhanden ist. Es ist unwahrscheinlich, dass diese Wortfamilie etwas zu tun hat mit leiten, geleiten, begleiten.

Comment: Note that there are also cases where *the same verb*, with the same prefix, can have two different conjugations (regular and irregular) depending on the use case. For example, "erschrecken": "du hast mich erschreckt", but "ich bin erschrocken".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of some more examples; (and I guess that there are still even more):

> **fehlen - fehlte - gefehlt
>
>   be-/empfehlen - be-/empfahl - be-/empfohlen**

*fehlen* comes via French from Latin *fallere*. *be-/empfehlen* is unrelated and inherited from Germanic.

> **bergen - barg - geborgen
>
>   beherbergen - beherbergte - beherbergt**

*beherbergen* is derived from the noun *Herberge*; interestingly, *Herberge* itself contains the verb/root of *bergen*.

> **preisen - pries - gepriesen
>
>   bepreisen - bepreiste - bepreist**

*bepreisen* is derived from the noun *Preis*; both *preisen* and *Preis* come from Latin *pretium/pretiare*.

> **reiten - ritt - geritten
>
>   (vor)bereiten - bereitete (vor) - (vor)bereitet**

As mentioned by someone in the comments, these two forms are (not very closely) related.

> **wachsen - wuchs - gewachsen
>
>   einwachsen - wachste ein - eingewachst** (from *Wachs*, wax)

The roots of these two verbs seem to be unrelated: *wachsen* (to grow) comes from the Indo-european root **aug-* (increase). *Wachs* (wax) comes from **ueg-* (weave).

**How common is this?**
I think there are not so much verbs where this phenomenon occurs (small *type frequency*); but some of these verbs are quite common, e.g. *fehlen, empfehlen, reiten, vorbereiten* (high *token frequency*).

Comment: It is worth noting that "einwachsen" has a [second meaning](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einwachsen_wachsen_sprieszen) that _is_ related to "wachsen". In this meaning it has the same irregular conjugation as "wachsen".

Comment: AFAIK "preisen - pries - gepriesen" is a rare example of a regular verb that became a strong one.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite rare indeed.
There are certainly similar examples, but at the moment I don't have any that come to mind.

On the above:

`entgleiten` is being handled like `gleiten` as they have a similar definition.

`begleiten` follows the word `leiten` in terms of grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one:

> reiten / ritt / geritten

vs.

> bereiten / bereitete / bereitet

I have no time at the moment to check it out, but I'm pretty sure that it is the same case as in your question: *reiten* and *bereiten* are etymologically unrelated.

Comment: Well, they are. The common root is "reigh"(to ride).  But that was long long time ago. "reiten" is just the original root, "bereiten" is derived of a word that had already detached and meant "ready". At that time, no one associated it with "reiten" and hence the conjugation was regular.

Comment: It's interesting to learn that *ready* and *reiten* are related - as are *fertig* and *fahren*.