# Regular verbs with irregular participle form as adjective

Tags: verb

The verb **verwirren** is a regular verb, with past and perfect forms

> verwirrte, hat verwirrt

However, the related form **verworren** is still in use as an adjective. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verworren) explains the etymology:

> **verworren: Herkunft**
>
> mittelhochdeutsch, althochdeutsch verworren, 2. Partizip des ehemaligen starken Verbs ↑verwirren

What are some other examples of verbs that used to be irregular but has become regular, but the irregular participle form is nevertheless still maintained as an adjective? How common is this phenomenon?

Note: [This question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/regular-compound-verbs-with-irregular-root-verbs) is related, but different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ***verschollen*** originates from a participle of *verschallen,* which is now regular.
- ***erlaucht*** und ***durchlaucht*** originate from participles of the verbs that have become *er-* and *durchleuchten.*
- *hart **gesotten*** comes from the irregular conjugation of *sieden (sott, gesotten),* which is almost extinct now (at least in my experience).
- ***voll*** originates from a participle of a verb that has become the regular verb *füllen.*
- ***gediegen*** was once a participle of *gedeihen,* which is still irregular but whose past participle is *gediehen* now.
- ***bescheiden*** originates from a participle of *bescheiden,* which is still irregular but whose past participle is *beschieden* now.

You can find *verworren* and the above (except *gesotten*) by searching the online Duden for `"eigentlich Partizip"`, `"Partizip des ehemaligen"`, `"ursprünglich Partizip"`, `"altes Partizip"`, `"veraltetes Partizip"` (the search ignores numbers). Unless I missed something, these searches do not yield any additional results. This suggests there aren’t many more similar cases and thus that this is a rather rare phenomenon.

Comment: +1 for the searching strategy

Answer (score 3):

Until now, I haven't found any other words that match your criteria completely.

[Verlogen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verlogen) is an old participle that has "lost" its verb, i.e. the related verb "verlügen / verliegen" is completely out of use. Same story for [gewitzt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gewitzt), which belongs to the extinct "witzen".

[Erhaben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erhaben) is another old participle, but the verb [erheben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erheben) is still irregular and has now "erhoben" as its past participle.

And finally there are [schaffen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schaffen), [bewegen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bewegen_schwaches_Verb) and [verweben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verweben) that exist as both regular and irregular verbs (with different meanings).

Answer (score 1):

*[Gewandt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gewandt_routiniert_wendig)* wird meiner Meinung nach als Partizip von *wenden* nicht mehr verwendet. Zumindest dürfte das für den Westen Deutschlands gelten (und wahrscheinlich auch für den Norden).

Als Adjektiv ist es aber durchaus gängig und bedeutet so viel wie *geschickt*.

Comment: "den Kopf zur Seite gewandt", "er hat sich an XYZ gewandt" - [wenden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wenden) ist sowohl stark als auch schwach in Gebrauch. Hier liegt mMn eher der Fall vor, dass das Partizip als Adjektiv eine weitere Bedeutung hat, die im Ursprungsverb nicht (mehr?) vorhanden ist.

Comment: @Matthias Das ist der Grund, warum ich in meiner Antwort schon ausgeschlossen habe, das es für ganz Deutschland gilt. Dein erstes Beispiel klingt für mich ganz unnatürlich. Ich sage zwar "den Kopf wenden", würde aber "den Kopf zur Seite gedreht" sagen. Im zweiten Beispiel ist es für mich eindeutig "gewendet": "An wen hast du dich gewendet? – Ich habe mich an den und den gewendet."

Comment: Laut Duden sind die Formen mit 'a' häufiger, außer in den Verwendungen, in denen nur 'e' verwandt / verwendet [sic!] wird. Ob es da regionale Unterschiede gibt, wäre eine interessante Frage.

Answer (score 0):

I think, for reasons of a more clear arrangement, this should be answered in a community answer. I guess, we might still find other examples. So let's go:

## clear cases

- **bescheiden** (though the recent participle is actually the irregular form, and the regular form is sunk into the separate adjective, it might be listed here as well)
- **erhaben**
- **erlaucht**, durchlaucht
- **gediegen**
- **gesotten**
- **gewitzt**
- **verlogen**
- **verschollen**
- **voll**
- **verworren**

## disputable cases

- **bescheiden**; though the recent participle is actually the irregular form, and the regular form is sunk into the separate adjective, it might be listed here as well
- **verwandt** "ist hervorgegangen aus dem Part. Prät. von frühnhd. *verwenden* im Sinne von ‘in eine bestimmte Richtung, auf ein bestimmtes Ziel hinwenden, hinweisen, verweisen’" ([Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verwandt)); though the verb "verwenden" still exists today, it does not longer have this meaning

Answer (score -1):

The verb »winken« (to wave) is an example for this:

Most common usage is regular:

> Ich winke. Ich winkte. Ich habe **gewinkt**.

But, specially in Austria an southern parts of Germany, you will also hear (and read in newspapers since it is not dialect, but a variation of standard german) this mixed form (Präterium is regular, Partizip II is irregular):

> Ich winke. Ich winkte. Ich habe **gewunken**.

Also »backen« (to bake), but here it is the Präterium that differs:

> Ich backe Brot. Ich **backte** Brot. Ich habe Brot gebacken.
>   Ich backe Brot. Ich **buk** Brot. Ich habe Brot gebacken.

Same with »hauen« (to hammer):

> Ich haue auf den Tisch. Ich **haute** auf den Tisch. Ich habe auf den Tisch gehauen.
>   Ich haue auf den Tisch. Ich **hieb** auf den Tisch. Ich habe auf den Tisch gehauen.

Senden (to send):

> Ich sende eine E-Mail. Ich **sendete** E-Mail. Ich habe eine E-Mail gesendet.
>   Ich sende eine E-Mail. Ich **sandte** E-Mail. Ich habe eine E-Mail gesendet.

But there are also examples where the meaning changes:

Saugen (to vacuumclean / to suck):

> Ich sauge den Teppich. Ich **saugte** den Teppich. Ich habe den Teppich **gesaugt**.
>   Ich sauge das Getränk durch einen Strohhalm. Ich **sog** das Getränk... Ich habe das Getränk ... **gesogen**.

Comment: Leider passt keines der Verben zur Frage. OP sucht Wörter mit heutzutage ausschließlich regulärer Form, wo aber eine alte irreguläre Form des Partizips immer noch als gängiges Adjektiv verwendet wird. "gewunken" ist für mich keine alte Form, zumal ich "gewinkt" noch nie gehört habe. Auch "gesaugt"/"gesogen" passt nicht, da "gesogen" als Konjugation nicht unbedingt veraltet ist, und vor allen es kein (relativ gesehen) gängiges Adjektiv ist. Alle anderen Beispiele haben keine unterschiedliche Partizip-Form (gehiebt und gebuk gibt es nicht, gesandet stammt von sanden ab)

Comment: @Em1 Laut verschiedenen Bänden des _Duden_ ist „gewinkt“ das korrekte Partizip II von „winken“. Die stark flektierte Form „gewunken“ ist in der Umgangssprache häufig, gilt aber als standardsprachlich nicht korrekt.

Comment: @Loong Interessant. "Gewinkt" klingt für mich wie die Konjugation eines 3 jährigen Kindes, genau so wie "gefliegt" und so.

Comment: @Loong In der [Online-Ausgabe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/winken) liest sich das nicht mehr ganz so strikt: "2. Partizip gewinkt, auch, besonders umgangssprachlich: gewunken".

Comment: @Loong: Im ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch; 39. Auflage von 2001) stehen sowohl »gewinkt« als auch »gewunken«. Somit ist »gewunken« zumindest in Österreichischem Deutsch standardsprachlich sehr wohl korrekt.